# throwing a dice infinite number of times

Tags: probability

Suppose we are throwing a dice infinite number of times. What is the probability, that the sequence $(1,2,3,4,5,6)$ will appear infinite number of times?

I considered using Borel-Cantelli lemma, but I don't know how to choose independent events.

Also by Kolmogorov 0-1 law it seams, that the answer is $1$ or $0$.

Comment: Consider the events $E_0,E_1,E_2,E_3,\dots$ where $E_n$ is the event that positions $6n,6n+1,6n+2,6n+3,6n+4,6n+5$ in the sequence of rolls host are the results $(1,2,3,4,5,6)$ respectively.  Questions to continue: Is $E_i$ independent of $E_j$ for $i\neq j$?  What is $Pr(E_i)$?  What is $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} \sum\limits_{i=1}^n Pr(E_i)$?  What does this imply?  Use the second borel-cantelli lemma.  Note, this proves a stronger result than what is asked for, but it implies the weaker result.

Comment: Suppose you had a $6^6$-sided die, where each face had a sequence of six digits taken from $\{1,2,3,4,5,6\}$.  How many times would you expect to see the “face” $(1,2,3,4,5,6)$ come up?

Comment: @MatthewLeingang unfortunately, expected value being large does not imply a probability of one.  Consider the scenario where we first flip a coin.  If tails, we stop there.  If heads, we roll the dice infinitely many times.  The expected number of times we see the subsequence $(1,2,3,4,5,6)$ is unbounded, however the probability that we have infinitely many occurrences is clearly at most $0.5$.

Comment: @JMoravitz: You're right.  I should not have used *expect* when I wasn't thinking about expected value.

Comment: @MatthewLeingang thanks, really nice solution, thank you for your help! :)

Comment: @Maciej more of a vague idea than a solution, but if it helps you I'm glad.

Comment: One possible argument is described in my answer to this question (adapt it by interpreting "returns to $0$" as "123456 occurs"): http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1571625/does-a-random-walk-is-recurrent-mean-it-returns-to-0-with-probability-1-o/1571675#1571675

Comment: What would be the probability of throwing a 6 if the dice is thrown an infinite number of times? 1?